# a conjecture about Hamiltonian graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a simple graph and $V(G)=V(C)\bigcup \{u_1,...,u_n\}$,where $C$ is a $2n$-cycle in $G$ and $V(C)=\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\}$ such that

$(1)V(C)\bigcap \{u_1,...,u_n\}=\varnothing$;

$(2)E(G)=\{a_1u_1,u_1b_1,a_2u_2,u_2b_2,...,a_nu_n,u_nb_n\}\bigcup E(C)$.

I think there must exists a proper subset $S$ of $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ such that $G-S$ is a Hamiltonian graph,is it ture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is right.It is equivalent to the claim below:

Let G be a simple graph which is a $2n$-cycle equipped with $n$ chords such that $G$ is $3$-regular,in other words,the set of the $n$ chords is a perfect matching of $G$(that is,every vertex of $G$ is matched).Then there must exist at least two different $2n$-cycles in $G$.

The proof is given by Tony Huynh,see my another question:[Does this graph contain at least two Hamiltonian cycles?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145531/an-interesting-conjecture-about-even-cycle).

Comment: So, what's that second cycle in my example?

Comment: $a_1$-$a_2$-$u_2$-$b_2$-$b_3$-$u_3$-$a_3$-$a_8$-$u_8$-$b_8$-$b_6$-$b_5$-$b_4$-$u_4$-$a_4$-$a_5$-$a_6$-$a_7$-$u_7$-$b_7$-$b_1$-$u_1$-$a_1$-,so $G-\{u_5,u_6\}$ is a Hamiltonian graph.

Comment: Indeed. Ok, I'll delete my "non-answer" then :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here $C_{2n}$ is a cycle of length $2n$ s.t. $V(C_{2n})=\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\}$,where $a_i$ adjacent to $a_{i+1}$,$b_i$ adjacent to $b_{i+1}$ (for $ 1 \leq i <n $) and $a_1$ adjacent to $b_n$,$a_n$ adjacent to $b_1$.Take  $S$ =$\{u_2,...,u_{n-1}\}$. Then $V(G-S)=\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n,u_1,u_n\}$ and $E(G-S)=\{a_1u_1,u_1b_1,a_nu_n,u_nb_n\}\bigcup E(C_{2n})$.A Hamiltonian cycle: $a_nu_nb_nb_{n-1}...b_1u_1a_1a_2...a_{n-1}a_n$.So $G-S$ is a Hamiltonian graph.

Comment: You do not know the edges except they form a cycle (the enumeration $a_j,b_j$ has nothing to do with the cycle order).

Comment: fedja,Thank you for your explaining!

Comment: So u want to say in the cycle $C$ $a_1$ adjacent to $b_2$ and $b_n$?

Comment: No,I just want to say the set of vertices of $C$ is $\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...b_n\}$.

Comment: but u should have to know a well-order(@ adjacentcy of the vertices of $C$),then u can find a Hamiltonian cycle. In above ans : without loss of generality I had define the  edges of the graph $C$  and then we show that $G-S$ is  a Hamiltonian graph.So in general u can also claim that.

Comment: The order in $\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\}$ has nothing to do with the cycle order.