# Does this graph contain at least two Hamiltonian cycles?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

Let $G$ be a simple graph which is a $2n$-cycle together with $n$ chords such that $G$ is $3$-regular.  In other words, the set of $n$ chords is a perfect matching of $G$.

I conjecture that for every such graph $G$, there must exist at least two different $2n$-cycles in $G$. Can you prove it or give a counterexample?

Comment: True. The number of Hamilton cycles through any edge of a cubic graph is even.

Comment: This actually follows from a comment of domotorp at your question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152204/the-length-of-paths-in-a-specific-graph

Comment: Hello,Daniel Soltész,Sorry to answer you so late.I asked this question much earlier than the question you mentioned above when I really did not know Smith's theorem.In fact,this question is just the simplest situation that derive from my later question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152204/the-length-of-paths-in-a-specific-graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof of Gordon's claim.  We will prove something slightly stronger.

**Claim.**
Let $G$ be a $d$-regular graph with $d$ odd.  Then for every $e \in E(G)$, there is an even number of Hamiltonian cycles using $e$.

*Proof.* Let $e=uv$ and let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of Hamiltonian paths in $G$ that start at $u$ and use the edge $e$.  Suppose that $P$ is such a path with ends $u$ and $w$.  Note that for any edge $wv$ with $v \neq u$, there is exactly one other Hamiltonian path $P_{wv} \in \mathcal{H}$ contained in $P \cup \{wv\}$. Create an auxiliary graph $G'$ with $V(G')=\mathcal{H}$ and if $P \in \mathcal{H}$ has ends $uw$, then $P$ is adjacent to $P_{wv}$ for all edges $wv$ with $v \neq u$.  Finish by observing that there is a 1-1 correspondence between Hamiltonian cycles in $G$ using $e$ and odd-degree vertices of $G'$.  Hence, there are an even number of them, as required.

Since your graph has at least one Hamiltonian cycle, it necessarily has at least two of them by the claim.

Comment: Tony Huynh，Thank you very much.In your claim,the condition "$d$-regular" can be turned into "the degree of every vertex is odd".

Comment: Is there any analogue of the Claim for the case when you're interested in edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles? e.g. if $G$ is $5$-regular and contains a Hamilton cycle, might it be true that there is always a 2nd Hamilton cycle which shares no edges with the first? (I guess no for trivial edge-connectivity reasons, so maybe rule that out as well.)