# The length of paths in a specific graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $K$ be the set of all the $2$-elements subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, then $|K|= \binom{n}{2}$. Define 
$$S=\left\{P\subseteq K:\bigcup_{I\in P}I=\{1,2,...,n\}\right\}.$$

For any $P\in S$,define a simple graph $G_P$:

$(1)$ $G_P$ has $n+|P|$ vertices and $V(G_P)=\{v_i:i=1,2,...,n\}\bigcup\{w_{\{j,k\}}:\{j,k\}\in P\}$;

$(2)$ $E(G_P)=\{v_iv_{i+1}:i=1,2,...,n-1\}\bigcup\{w_{\{j,k\}}v_j,w_{\{j,k\}}v_k:\{j,k\}\in P\}$.

Obviously there is a path between $v_1$ and $v_n$ in $G_P$ whose length is $n-1$. I guess for any $P\in S$, there must exist another path between $v_1$ and $v_n$ in $G_P$ whose length is larger than $n-1$; is it true?

Comment: If you suppose that P is (or contains) a perfect matching, then this should follow from Smith's theorem which claims that in any cubic graph G there must be an even number of Hamiltonian cycles through any fixed edge uv. Probably the general version can also be reduced to this case.

Comment: Yes，I know that and I have tried hard to do what you said.But I can not work it out and I believe if my guess is right,there must exist some different method for this problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are just considering all graphs on $n$ vertices with minimum degree 1, then subdividing each edge and adding a path through all original vertices?

Comment: I am sorry,nvcleemp.I do not quite understand what you mean.Can you explain your meaning in detail?

Comment: By now I am convinced that this statement might be pretty hard. See related problems at http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/regs/extraham.html

Comment: What I meant is this: each P corresponds to a labelled graph in a canonical way, i.e., the sets are the edges. Since the union of the sets needs to be equal to the complete set, all of this vertices need to appear at least once, hance, the graph has minimum degree 1. The graph $G_P$ can be constructed by subdividing each edge in that  graph and adding a path through the vertices 1 to $n$ (in that order). This does not imply an answer, but sometimes looking at a problem in a different way can help seeing things, so I wanted to make sure that I have understand your construction correctly.

Comment: nvcleemp,I am so sorry to answer your reply so late and I looked at your reply very carefully just now.Yes,You have precisely understood my construction.For my question above,I did not find any good way to approach it.Do you have any good idea?